# Ionic http.setRequestTimeout not working for Android

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native

http.setRequestTimeout for Android has no effect, whereas iOS works perfectly. I am using IONIC 5 with Angular. Any suggestions?

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

...

const GetRequestTimeoutSeconcs: number = 30;

...

private http: HTTP,

...

private sendGetCommand(ip: string, command: string): any{
    let _self = this;

    // Send message
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      _self.http.setRequestTimeout(GetRequestTimeoutSeconcs);
      _self.http.get('http://' + ip + '/' + command, {}, {})
      .then(data => {

        resolve(_self.decodeMessage(data.data));
      })
      .catch(error => {

        reject(error);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Do you declare `http` in the constructor?

Comment: Yes, http is properly declared in the constructor. It also works in general. The gets and posts work well. The only thing which is not working is _self.http.setRequestTimeout() method on Android. iOS works fine thought.